# Using binary operator with unichar and String

Tags: ios, swift, binary-operators, unichar

I am attempting to use a binary operator to compare two values:

```
character = (xxx as NSString).characterAtIndex(2)
if character == "1" {
    //do this thingy   
}
```

Now I receive the failure message Binary Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type unichar or String.
I have also attempted to convert the character:

```
if String(character) == "1"
```

Does not work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `unichar` is a type aliased to a 16-bit integer, you need to "wrap" it in `UnicodeScalar` function for the comparison:

```
if UnicodeScalar(character) == "1" {
    //do this thingy   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach.  Change the way you are getting `character` from the `String`:

```
let xxx = "321"
let character = xxx[advance(xxx.startIndex, 2)]
if (character == "1") {
    println("it is a 1")
}
```

output:

> "it is a 1"